# Некорректная повторная сериализация после удаления

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;



namespace Database
{
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line = "";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("option.ini.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default))
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        List<Person> employees = new List<Person>();
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        if (line == "xml")
        {
            if (File.Exists("person.xml"))
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("person.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    List<Person> newEmployees = (List<Person>)xs.Deserialize(fs);
                    Console.WriteLine("Объект десериализован");
                    employees = newEmployees;
                }
            }
        }
        if (line == "bin")
        {
            if (File.Exists("person.dat"))
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("person.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    List<Person> newEmployees = (List<Person>)bf.Deserialize(fs);
                    employees = newEmployees;
                }
            }
        }
        if (line == "bin"||line == "xml")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Установите значение bin или xml в файле option.ini.txt");
        }
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Введите команду:");
            string com = Console.ReadLine();
            if (com.ToLower() == "exit")
            {
                if (line == "xml")
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("person.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        xs.Serialize(fs, employees);
                    }
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("person.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        bf.Serialize(fs, employees);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (com.ToLower() == "allsee")
            {
                if (line == "xml")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0}, Фамилия: {1}, Табельный номер {2}", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, employees.Select(p => p.Name)), string.Join(Environment.NewLine, employees.Select(p => p.Surname)), string.Join(Environment.NewLine, employees.Select(p => p.PersonnelNumber)));
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    continue;
                }
                if (line == "bin")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0}", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, employees.Select(p => p.Name)));
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (com.ToLower() == "del")
            {
                string n;
                Console.WriteLine("Name del?");
                n = Console.ReadLine();
                if (employees.Exists(p => p.Name == n))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < employees.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (employees[i].Name == n)
                        {
                            employees.Remove(employees[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Удаление прошло успешно.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Сотрудника с таким именем не существует!");
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
                continue;
            }
            if (com.ToLower() == "add")
            {
                string name;
                string surname;
                string personnelnumber;
                Console.WriteLine("Введите имя сотрудника:");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Введите фамилию сотрудника:");
                surname = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Введите табельный номер сотрудника:");
                personnelnumber = Console.ReadLine();
                Person p = new Person(name, surname, personnelnumber);
                employees.Add(p);
                continue;
            }
            if (com.ToLower() != "add")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Доступные команды:");
                Console.WriteLine("\tadd создать запись сотрудника");
                Console.WriteLine("\texit Выйти и сохранить данные");
                Console.WriteLine("\tallsee Выйти и сохранить данные");
                Console.ReadKey();
                continue;
            }
        }         
    }
}  
   [Serializable]
   public class Person
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Surname { get; set; }
       public string PersonnelNumber { get; set; }
       public Person()
       { }
       public Person(string name, string surname, string personnelnumber)
       {
           Name = name;
           Surname = surname;
           PersonnelNumber = personnelnumber;
       }
   }
```

}

Здравствуйте! При добавлении сотрудников  добавление проходит успешно. При закрытии программы происходит сериализация в файл person.xml тоже успешная. При следующем открытии происходит чтение. А вот при удалении сотрудника удаление тоже проходит успешно, но при выходе уже некорреткная сериализация. 


  
    valentin
    ivanov
    1111
  
me>valentin
    ivanov
    1111
  

Как следствие при вызове любой команды exeption. Как исправить?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Person>
    <Name>valentin</Name>
    <Surname>evseev</Surname>
    <PersonnelNumber>1111</PersonnelNumber>
  </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>me>valentin</Name>
    <Surname>evseev</Surname>
    <PersonnelNumber>1111</PersonnelNumber>
  </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>

Comment: Когда закрываете приложение, вам нужно перезаписывать файл полностью. Вместо OpenOrCreate при закрытии используйте Create. Иначе новые данные записываются поверх старых, а остатки старых мешают десериализации.

Comment: @qzavyer ваш комментарий должен быть ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда закрываете приложение, вам нужно перезаписывать файл полностью. Вместо `OpenOrCreate` при закрытии используйте `Create`. Иначе новые данные записываются поверх старых, а остатки старых мешают десериализации.

Comment: Да, теперь все ок!